# Cached sharing information

Tags: caching, share, facebook-sharer, page-title

For some reason the share link title is NOT updating, even though the og:title and share query var &t="" value is correct.

The URL with the problem is...
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iRB_O0hduHQ

If you view this through the Facebook debug page it's correct, but when viewing via the Facebook share dialog it's wrong.
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DiRB_O0hduHQ

Any ideas how to clear this or force a refresh on the share cache? It's clearly a cache associated to the Facebook domain. It's rumoured hitting the Facebook debug page will refresh the cache, but this has had no effect.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Its not a rumor - its [documented behaviour](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Linter](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to refresh the caching of your `og:tags`.
From the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/) :

> **Editing Meta Tags**
>
> You can update the attributes of your page by updating your page's
>  tags. Note that og:title and og:type are only editable
> initially - after your page receives 50 likes the title becomes fixed,
> and after your page receives 10,000 likes the type becomes fixed.
> These properties are fixed to avoid surprising users who have liked
> the page already. Changing the title or type tags after these limits
> are reached does nothing, your page retains the original title and
> type.
>
> **For the changes to be reflected on Facebook, you must force your page
> to be scraped. The page is scraped when an admin for the page clicks
> the Like button or when the URL is entered into the Facebook URL
> Linter.**